# how to implement nextpagetoken for youtube api

Tags: php, youtube-api

I Tried the below code:

```
$api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&pageToken=CAoQAA&playlistId='.$playlist_id. '&key=' . 
$api_key;
```

I appreciate if you give a solution.

Comment: Did you try this mam https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727560/retrieve-all-playlist-entry-youtube-api-v3-using-pagetoken ?

Comment: i tried, but im new to json, please help me to find a solution

Comment: $api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId='.$playlist_id. '&key=' . $api_key;

Comment: the above code i used, i need to show all videos from my youtube list. @Mittul At TechnoBrave

Answer (score 0):

You place nextPageToken in your pageToken parameter. You can check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727560/retrieve-all-playlist-entry-youtube-api-v3-using-pagetoken) for actual code samples:

```
   // checking if nextPageToken exist than return our function and 
      // insert $next_page_token with value inside nextPageToken
    if(isset($searchResponse['nextPageToken'])){
          // return to our function and loop again
        return youtube_search($query, $max_results, $searchResponse['nextPageToken']);
    }
```

Also, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253925/youtube-data-api-v3-php-search-pagination) for additional reference.